# "***stack smashing detected***:<unknown> terminated core dumped"en ejecucion de una funcion dos veces con los mismos parametros en C

Tags: c, matrices, stack

Implemente un código que permite calcular los tiempos de ejecución para el análisis de rendimiento en matrices a través de los métodos de ordenamiento Row major(ordenamiento por filas) y Column major(ordenamiento por columnas) para una matriz cuadrada.

Generé dos arreglos que acumulen los tiempos de ejecución de ambos tipos de ordenamiento para una misma operación y luego, una vez ordenados, hallar la mediana como medida de tendencia central para mi análisis.

Sin embargo al ejecutarlo, con el arreglo de los tiempos de Row major no hay ningún problema para ordenarlos pero cuando utilizo el ordenamiento de Column major e imprimo el arreglo ordenado este se desplaza en una posición y en el terminal me pone el siguiente error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo curioso de esto es que se supone que debería de funcionar igual ya que se tienen los mismos arreglos con el mismo tipo de variable,con el mismo tamaño. Sin embargo, el error sólo se repite para el arreglo de Column major.

Adjunto evidencia:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Asimismo como adjunto mi código completo comentado que permita el análisis:

Está es mi función para el ordenamiento del vector:

```
void ordenar_arreglo(int tam,float vector[]){
//algoritmo para ordenar el arreglo
float aux;
for(int i=0;i<tam;i++){
    aux=0.0;
    for(int j=0;j<(tam-i);j++){
        if(vector[j]>vector[j+1]){
            aux=vector[j];
            vector[j]=vector[j+1];
            vector[j+1]=aux;
        }
    }
}
```

Los tiempos los obtuve así:

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
    //parte de row major
    inicio_r=clock();
    transpuesta_rm(dim,matriz1);
    final_r=clock();
    t_r=1000000*((float)(final_r-inicio_r)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    tiempos_row[i]=t_r;
    //parte de column major
    inicio_c=clock();
    transpuesta_cm(dim,matriz2);
    final_c=clock();
    t_c=1000000*((float)(final_c-inicio_c)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    tiempos_column[i]=t_c;
}
```

luego usé esta función para mostrar los vectores:

```
void mostrar_vector(int dim,float vector[]){
printf("[");
for(int i=0;i<dim;i++){
    printf(" %f ",vector[i]);
}
printf("]\n");
```

}

y finalmente lo que le solicito al programa es lo siguiente:

```
int tam=10;
ordenar_arreglo(tam,tiempos_row);
//ordenar_arreglo(tam,tiempos_column); aca hay error

printf("tiempos de row major\n");
mostrar_vector(tam,tiempos_row);
//printf("tiempos de column major\n");
//mostrar_vector(tam,tiempos_column);

return 0;
```

Asimismo por si tienen duda acerca de como inicialicé mis arreglos le adjunto la parte correspondiente:

```
clock_t inicio_r,final_r,inicio_c,final_c;
int dim = 500;
int matriz1[dim][dim];
int matriz2[dim][dim];
float tiempos_row[10];
float tiempos_column[10];
//llenado para 1
llenado(dim,matriz1);
//lenado para 2
llenado(dim,matriz2);
float t_c;
float t_r;
```

Adjunto mi archivo para que hagan las pruebas correspondientes: [Archivo en C](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1FbQkY0Jw__CKq4OmMKBXBIiQA0sI3B63?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2):

El error `*** stack smashing detected ***` dice que durante la ejecución se detectó que sobre-escribiste el stack.

En la función

```
void ordenar_arreglo(int tam,float vector[]){
    //algoritmo para ordenar el arreglo
    float aux;
    for(int i=0;i<tam;i++){
        aux=0.0;
        for(int j=0;j<(tam-i);j++){
            if(vector[j]>vector[j+1]){
                aux=vector[j];
                vector[j]=vector[j+1];
                vector[j+1]=aux;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Cuando `i == 0`, la variable `j` va desde 0 hasta `(tam-i)`, o sea que el ciclo interno queda así:

```
for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
```

Dentro del ciclo asignas a `vector[j+1]`, o sea asignas a `vector[10]`, el undécimo elemento en un vector de 10. Ese es el error.

`Stack Smashing` es causado por el mecanimo de protección usado por el compilador para detectar rebalses del stack (`stack overflow`).

El compilador agrega variables de protección  (se llaman `canarios`) con valores conocidos en el stack. Si al terminar la función se detecta que estos valores ya no son los mismos, se genera el mensaje.

Puedes darte cuenta de que cada vez que se produce el error, el resultado mostrado contiene un valor que no viene de tus datos, como aqui:

```
[ -17231249408.000000  1924.000000  1936.000000  1958.000000  1989.000000  2016.000000  2074.000000  2134.000000  2307.000000  2382.000000 ]
```

El primer valor está obviamente fuera de orden. Es el `canario` que accediste via `vector[10]`.

Tienes que cambiar tu función de ordenamiento.